# Method for initializing a priority queue with a lambda compare

Tags: c++, lambda, tuples, priority-queue

I'm trying to initialize a custom priority queue, which is in a class as a member object. It takes a tuple and uses a lambda function as the comparator.

I've tried a few different methods of setting this up all seem to fail on different accords,

In the `usedhere.h` file I have:

```
 typedef std::tuple<trainz*,R_linez*,float> train_tuple;

auto tup_cmp =[](train_tuple lhs, train_tuple rhs)
  {
    return std::get<2>(lhs) < std::get<2>(rhs);
  };

using P_que_trainz = std::priority_queue<train_tuple,std::vector<train_tuple>,decltype(tup_cmp)>;

class usedhere{
private : 
P_que_trainz trainLine_que(tup_cmp);
};
```

This gives:

> error:  ‘`tup_cmp`’ is not a type

If I just do `P_que_trainz trainLine_que;` in the header and 
`P_que_trainz trainLine_que(tup_cmp);`
 in the constructor, I get a mess of error about template deduction fail.

If I move the lambda to inside the class declaration, like this:

```
class usedhere
{
 private : 
 auto tup_cmp =[](train_tuple lhs, train_tuple rhs) ... etc
};
```

then I get

> `auto` is not allowed in header.

If I just put `private: P_que_trainz trainLine_que();`, I get

> error: invalid use of member function. did you forget the ‘()’

When later I try using it in a function, say in 
`void usedhere::dispatchtrain(){ ...for (size_t i = 0; i< trainLine_que.size(); i++)...}`

I'm sure I'm just missing a simple order to it all.  But I'm out of ideas to experiment.

Comment: Use uniform initialization to init member variable `P_que_trainz trainLine_que{tup_cmp};`.

Comment: `P_que_trainz trainLine_que(tup_cmp);` is actually taken for a function declaration by the language, when `()` is used. Hence the `tup_cmp is not a type` error. As rafix pointed out you need to use `{}` for initialization within the class definition.

Comment: omg. yes ahhh  uniform initialization... yes yes. i always forget that   syntax thx you!

Answer (score 0):

**trainLine_que** is a member variable, so just create a constructor initializing it this way:

```
class usedhere {

public:
    usedhere() : trainLine_que(tup_cmp) {}

private:
    P_que_trainz trainLine_que;

};
```